# Focus object with specific Rotation in unity C#

Tags: unity, c#

I have different kind of objects with variable dimensions and placed at different position in a scene. I want to focus/display each object with the camera with a hard code rotation (north rotation). Like with specific camera rotation I want to focus the object that it completely show to the camera and center of the screen. For this reason, I have write this code snippet that
1

1. Get the position behind the specific focus object using
   `TransformPoint`
2. Provide the elevation using the largest `extent` of the `bound` so that it display maximum area of the object.
3. Assign the `position` and the fixed `rotation`

   ```
    Vector3 dest = destination.transform.TransformPoint(0, 0, behindPositionDistance);// GetBehindPosition(destination.transform, behindPositionDistance, elevation);
    Debug.Log(dest);
    float eleveMax = Mathf.Max(destination.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.extents.x, destination.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.extents.z);
    dest = new Vector3(dest.x, eleveMax, dest.z);
    camera.transform.position = dest;
    camera.transform.rotation = lookNorth;
   ```

But the problem is, it is not accurately working with all objects as every object is at different position and dimension. I want to focus the full object using the camera but without changing the rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet thanks to one of unity forum thread.

```
public void SetPosition(Bounds bounds)
    {
        Camera camera = Camera.main;
        float cameraDistance = 1.0f; // Constant factor
        Vector3 objectSizes = bounds.max - bounds.min;
        float objectSize = Mathf.Max(objectSizes.x, objectSizes.y, objectSizes.z);
        float cameraView = 2.0f * Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * camera.fieldOfView); // Visible height 1 meter in front
        float distance = cameraDistance * objectSize / cameraView; // Combined wanted distance from the object
        distance += 0.5f * objectSize; // Estimated offset from the center to the outside of the object
        camera.transform.position = bounds.center - distance * camera.transform.forward;
    }
```